# How to choose the output format of the BlueGriffon editor?

Tags: html, xhtml, editor, wysiwyg

Wikipedia says that BlueGriffon can create and edit pages in accordance to HTML 4, XHTML 1.0, HTML 5 and XHTML 5. But i can't find where to choose the output format, it always creates an xhtml file when saving. Could someone give me a hint?

Thanks,
Stephan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out you can't. You can pick your new documents format, but afterwards you can't change.